# Extracting images from a .RTF file with Python

Tags: python, rtf

does anyone know how to extract or copy images from a .rtf file ?

I have tryed to look for a solution but from what I found, all of the libraries and articles people cite no longer exist or have non-existen documentation.

Comment: If you have one of those dead links, you can probably resurrect it at the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.

Comment: I was able to find the RTF spec at https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/Archive_References/[MSFT-RTF].pdf.  I may use that as the basis for my own answer if I find the time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since I didn't find a straightforward solution to extract images from a .rtf file I came up with a workaround.

I used the **win32com** lib to open the file and then saved it as a .docx:

```
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(RtfFilePath)
doc.SaveAs(saveDocxPath, FileFormat=16)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

This is way you can use **docx2txt** and other libraries that extract images from word files:

```
text = docx2txt.process("/path/your_word_doc.docx", '/home/example/img/')
```

Also I have found out that some images can be saved as .wmf, these files can't be extarcted this way. I have found a workaround for this by using commands.

```
subprocess.run(f"tar -x -f {FileToExtaract} -C {TargetFolder}")
```

The extracted images will be located in your **TargerFolder\word\media**.
You can convert them into any other image type using the **Pillow** library with this code:

```
from PIL import Image

Image.open("image.wmf").save("image.png")
```